# SelectMany in List: "type arguments cannot be inferred from usage"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to run the code below, but I'm getting an error on the first `SelectMany` statement: "The type arguments for method `'IEnumerable<TResult> System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany...'` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly".
Company has a list of `Employments`, I want to get a list with all `employments` of the company called `"Company1"`, and after I need to filter with the employee is currently working (when `EndDate` is null) and return a list only with their names.

I need to do it using Linq Queries.

```
var employees = FindAllCompanies()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Company1")
            .SelectMany(x => x.Employments)
            .Select(x => x.EmploymentEndDate == null)
            .SelectMany(x.Name);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have a typo, instead of

```
.Select(x => x.EmploymentEndDate == null)
```

you want

```
.Where(x => x.EmploymentEndDate == null)
```

If you select this you will get a `bool`, that has not a `Name` property, of course.

The final `SelectMany` is also wrong, instead of

```
.SelectMany(x.Name)
```

this

```
.Select(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, what you said was part of the problem, and helped me.
Besides that, I had a import problem with the class Employment in the Company, it was making my SelectMany don't work.